# Python : split a list dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list `prodemployees` that looks like this :

```
['prd1 employe4 employe2', ' prd2 employe2']
```

I need the values of this list to dynamically create the "where" statement of a query, I need the output to be like this :

```
WHERE (product = 'prd1' AND employe IN ('employe4','employe2'))
OR
(product = 'prd2' AND employe IN ('employe2'))
```

I hae tried splitting on whitespace each value of the list, and create a sublist containing the resulting values, but failed at using those values.

I'm new to Python, any help is appreciated.

```
splitOnSpace = []
for i in range(len(prodemployees)) :
  splitOnSpace = prodemployees[i].split()
    for j in range(len(splitOnSpace)) : 
       #this is where I should do something with splitOnSpace[j] I guess...
```

Comment: Is the space at the beginning of ' prd2 employe2' intentional?

Comment: Don't use `for i in range()` where a direct loop over the list would do.

Comment: noo the space is not intentional

Comment: From you have written I understand that you're storing in data structures relationship between product and employee. Consider using dictionary in place of a list, it'll be easier to use and maintain.

Comment: I suspect you meant to use `OR` to separate the subclauses of your query's criteria, otherwise it will always return zero rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a list after splitting, you can *slice* that list to get a sublist:

```
for prod_emp in prodemployees:
    prod_emp = prod_emp.split()
    prod, emp = prod_emp[0], prod_emp[1:]
```

Here `prod` is set to the first element of your split string, `emp` to a list of all elements but the first:

```
>>> prodemployees = ['prd1 employe4 employe2', ' prd2 employe2']
>>> for prod_emp in prodemployees:
...     prod_emp = prod_emp.split()
...     prod, emp = prod_emp[0], prod_emp[1:]
...     print prod, emp
... 
prd1 ['employe4', 'employe2']
prd2 ['employe2']
```

From here on out, I'd use SQL parameters to do the actual queries. Build the filters, then pass in the chain of all split arguments as one long parameter list:

```
from itertools import chain

filters = filters = ('(product=%s AND employee in ({}))'.format(', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(pe.split()) - 1))) for pe in prodemployees)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE {}'.format(
                   ' OR '.join(filters)),
               chain.from_iterable(pe.split() for pe in prodemployees))
```

Here `filters` generates suitable SQL with parameter placeholders:

```
>>> filters = ('(product=%s AND employee in ({}))'.format(', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(pe.split()) - 1))) for pe in prodemployees)
>>> list(filters)
['(product=%s AND employee in (%s, %s))', '(product=%s AND employee in (%s))']
>>> filters = ('(product=%s AND employee in ({}))'.format(', '.join('%s' for _ in range(len(pe.split()) - 1))) for pe in prodemployees)
>>> 'SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE {}'.format(
...                    ' OR '.join(filters))
'SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE (product=%s AND employee in (%s, %s)) OR (product=%s AND employee in (%s))'
```

which `.execute()` would fill into your query from the parameters that `chain.from_iterable()` provides:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(pe.split() for pe in prodemployees))
['prd1', 'employe4', 'employe2', 'prd2', 'employe2']
```

The `%s` placeholders used here are specific to certain types of database adapter; others may use `?` instead; check your database adapter documentation.

Comment: thank you for your effort! I have forgotten to mention that I don't previously know the length of `prodemployees `, the number of the second "AND" should be added dynamically depending on `prodemployees` length... How can I do this programatically please ?

Comment: Let's upvote to compensate. There are few more knowledgeable and helpful than Martijn Pieters and this is a good answer.

Comment: When I do : `print('SELECT * FROM CR WHERE {}'.format(' OR '.join(filters)),chain.from_iterable(pe.split() for pe in prodemployees))` it gives me : `('SELECT * FROM CR WHERE (product=%s AND employee in (%s))', <itertools.chain object at 0x00A4A9D0>)` why aren't the values shown ?

Comment: @user1734229: `itertools` functions return generators; these produce values on demand. That is why, in my answer, I called `list()` on the generator to demonstrate what sequence is produced.